# How do I get all the Keyframes I see other people using?

Tags: keyframes, dopesheet

I see people using all sorts of keyframes when they push "I". I cannot seem to get these options. When I push "I", I get the following: "All Channels", "Only selected channels", and "In active group".

How can I get these other options of keyframes for my projects?

I push "I" in the 3d view and get the menu I want. This only occurs in a new project and does not happen in a project that I have been working in a pop-up says, "No suitable context for active Keying Set".

I do not have the Key Set option in that window either. It skips right over it, from "Delta Scale" to "Location".

"All the other Keyframes" are yes, the Key sets. "Location, Rotation, scaling, locrot, locrotscale, rotscale, delta location, delta rotation, delta scale, visual location, visual rotation, visual scaling, visual locrot, visual locrotscale, visual locscale, and visual rotscale.

Comment: Press **I** in the 3D View. In the Dopesheet you can change the keyframe type by pressing **T** or the handle type by pressing **V** if you're using beziers.

Comment: @JosiahValentine Are you talking about [Keying Sets](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html?highlight=keying%20set#)?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. I needed to click the "x" in the active keying sets dropdown in the timeline window. that let me choose what I wanted when I hit "I" in all engine and projects. The "I" shortcut does not work if the keying set is set to "available". just hit the x thee so nothing appears in that window.

Also, the "I" shortcut will look different in the dope sheet than it will in the 3d view. I understand now, and hope that this is able to clear things up for other who may be confused as to what they should do.

Comment: The reason pressing 'i' doesn't work when the Available keying set is chosen is because the Available keying set only set keys on channels that have already been keyed. Once keyed by other means, choosing Available can be a handy way of ensuring that no new channels get keyed accidentally, and also ensures that all keyed channels will be keyed again when pressing 'i'.